# crop image with opencv in c

Tags: c, opencv, multidimensional-array, resize-crop

I want to crop 1 pixel from all sides of image.
My code works well in some margins but does not work well in some margins (ex. widthleft=widthright=heightup=heightdown=1).
I should use C not C++.

```
IplImage* edgecuter_v3(unsigned int height, unsigned int width,
    IplImage* p_in_img_grey) {
unsigned int widthleft, widthright, heightup, heightdown, heighteff;
unsigned int widtheff;
widthleft = 1;
widthright = 1;
heightup = 1;
heightdown = 1;
widtheff = width - widthleft - widthright;
heighteff = height - heightup - heightdown;

IplImage *p_out_img;

unsigned char *p_in_img_data;
p_in_img_data = (unsigned char *) p_in_img_grey->imageData;
unsigned char (*p_char_array_in)[width];
p_char_array_in = (unsigned char (*)[width]) p_in_img_data;

p_out_img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(widtheff, heighteff), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
unsigned char *p_out_img_data;
p_out_img_data = (unsigned char *) p_out_img->imageData;
unsigned char (*p_char_array_out)[widtheff];
p_char_array_out = (unsigned char (*)[widtheff]) p_out_img_data;

unsigned int row_indx;
unsigned int col_indx;
for (row_indx = 0; row_indx < heighteff ; row_indx++) {
    for (col_indx = 0; col_indx < widtheff; col_indx++) {
        p_char_array_out[row_indx ][col_indx ] =
                p_char_array_in[row_indx+heightup][col_indx+widthleft];
    }
}
cvNamedWindow("one", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("one", p_out_img);
cvWaitKey(0);
return p_out_img;}
```

I sweep index with other methods and assignments like but not work.

```
            p_char_array_out[row_indx ][col_indx ] =
                p_char_array_in[row_indx+heightup][col_indx+widthleft];
```

thanks lot

Comment: this post made a grown man cry.

Comment: Step 1) Convert your code to C++ and OpenCV 2.0+.  Step 2) Follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267191/how-to-crop-a-cvmat-in-opencv).

Comment: thanks. yes my first post and cry. 3 negative up to now. I should use C not C++;

Comment: Why do you have to use C rather than C++? The C API for OpenCV was superseded 5 years ago and is no longer supported.

Comment: :-))))...thanks. I did not know they discarded.  I'm new in opencv. ok i use C++ but i wanted to know the problem if it is from array assignment and not library.

Comment: Go through the first two tutorials here to understand the structure of `cv::Mat` http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/table_of_content_core/table_of_content_core.html#table-of-content-core

Comment: and yes  I want to work with pixels in SIMD for algorithms like sobel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. maybe useful for others.

1. Acording to this link [32bit boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368312/creating-opencv-mat-from-user-data-results-in-image-with-circular-shifted-column) "If the number of cols * pixel size isn't a multiple of 4 then each row if the image will be padded"
2. The right way for sweep is to use "widthStep" not "width" for considering pad

widthStep_r = p_in_img->widthStep;